# Google Script: How do I get my output in the console pasted in google sheets?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

This is my current code:

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
     sheet.appendRow(["Remove_Later", "Name", "Client", "Name of project", "Deliverables"]); //writes the headers
  var topFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("ThisIsTheFolderId");
  var topPath = "/";
  iterateSubFolders(topFolder, topPath);
}

function iterateSubFolders(callingFolder, callingPath) {

  var callingFolderName = callingFolder.getName();
  var callingFolderFullPath = callingPath + callingFolderName + "/";
  Logger.log(callingFolderFullPath);

  var childSubFolders = callingFolder.getFolders();
  while (childSubFolders.hasNext()) {
      var nextSubFolder = childSubFolders.next();
      iterateSubFolders(nextSubFolder, callingFolderFullPath);
  }
}
```

I have not been able to get the console output in a google sheet which i would like. I have no clue and have been struggling for hours now. Help is highly appreciated! Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

### You can return your console output to `myFunction` and pass it to `sheet.appendRow`

Sample:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var topFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("ThisIsTheFolderId");
  var topPath = "/";
  iterateSubFolders(topFolder, topPath);
  sheet.appendRow(["Remove_Later", "Name", "Client", "Name of project", "Deliverables", callingFolderFullPath]); //writes the headers
}

function iterateSubFolders(callingFolder, callingPath) {

  var callingFolderName = callingFolder.getName();
  var callingFolderFullPath = callingPath + callingFolderName + "/";
  sheet.appendRow([callingFolderFullPath]);
  var childSubFolders = callingFolder.getFolders();
  while (childSubFolders.hasNext()) {
      var nextSubFolder = childSubFolders.next();
      iterateSubFolders(nextSubFolder, callingFolderFullPath);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Is there a way to direct the output straight to the google sheets, so it runs faster? I do not need to see the output in the console, just in the google sheet if possible

Comment: also this doesnt add all the files i have in the folder - when i run this code I only get the name of the parent folder in google sheets

Comment: I updated my answer to show you a different way to implement ALL of your `callingFolderFullPath`s and without logs. Hope this helps!